# Why does a nmap scan give different results depending on whether it's run from inside or outside a LAN

Tags: firewalls, nmap

I am testing/setting up a Thompson TG585v7 router/firewall.

#### Results when running `nmap` from a computer INSIDE the LAN

```
$ sudo nmap -O 210.86.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-22 10:55 NZDT
Host is up (0.0049s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
23/tcp   open  telnet
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
1723/tcp open  pptp
```

#### Results when running `nmap` from a computer OUTSIDE the LAN

```
michael@trusty-ssd:~$ sudo nmap -Pn 210.86.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-22 11:10 NZDT
Host is up (0.038s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
1935/tcp open  rtmp
```

Is this happening because

- When scan is run from outside LAN firewall responds with rules from `INPUT` chain?
- When scan is run from inside LAN firewall responds with rules from `OUTPUT` chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal for external (WAN) and internal (LAN) traffic to follow different paths and for those paths to have different filtering behaviour. In most routers, even SOHO type devices, you will normally find at least 3 interfaces, WAN, LAN and WLAN. The LAN and WLAN traffic originates from within your network and devices connected in this way may have private non-routable IP addresses. The WAN interface is for connections from outside your network. If you own enough IP addresses i.e. you have a class C or your ISP has assigned you a range of IP addresses, devices inside your network may have a 'real' IP address which can be routed, but for smaller networks, it is more common for the internal network to have private IP addresses and a single public IP address, which is associated with your end of the WAN connection. In this case, your router will perform NAT (Network Address Translation) to map traffic from internal private IPs to your public IP and vice-versa for connection based protocols like TCP. You can also have port forwarding, which allows connections initiated from the outside to be routed to an IP within your network.

The difference you observe between internal and external scans is likely due to different firewall policies being applied to the traffic based on the source IP and possible the interface it comes in on. For example, you might filter out any attempts to connect via your WAN interface for IP addresses which are within your IP range and filter out connections from within your LAn/WLAN for IP addresses which are not within your IP range.

You may also filter access to ports/protocols/servers based on the source interface (LAN/WLAN, WAN) or the source IP address. You may also have multiple levels of filtering. An important concept in security is 'security in depth'. This refers to having more than one layer of defence. For example, your scan from outside the network could be filtered at the boarder firewall or it could be filtered at the server firewall. These days, its not uncommon to find filtering at the boarder, at the server and even at the application level.

There are also reactive and deep packet firwalls. For example, you might see different results from your external scans depending on the number of scan you perform or the time between scans or the number of hosts you scan. A reactive firewall will track what is occurring and if it sees a pattern which it feels is unusual or could represent bad guys trying to scan the network or a host, it might change how it is filtering or even provide misleading information. Deep packet inspection firewalls might even look at the packets your sending and decide they don't look like normal traffic and drop them.

Bottom line, the information you get back from a scan may not be telling you as much as you think and may not even be telling you the truth. The information is an indicator which needs to be combined with other information before you can draw conclusions on what is going on.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. Im getting the sense that if you want to be able to understand and configure the various paths and interfaces etc, You need a router whose operating system has great documentation and guides about its architecture and how to use it.

Comment: What is most important is to match the product with your requirements. To do this, you need to look at what your risk profile is (i.e. likelihood of someone trying to do something bad and consequence should they do it). Then find the product within your resource limits which will provide the right balance. There is no absolutes here and you will never have 100% protection. It is also estimated that 70% of security holes are caused by misconfiguration. Often it is better to have less sophisticated and correct than very sophisticated and wrong

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with that particular product, it is common for routers to distinguish between their WAN and LAN interfaces. Most routers aimed at consumers or small business users expect to be managed from the LAN, so block access to management interfaces from the WAN.

Packets from both the WAN and LAN traverse the INPUT chain, but the router would likely have rules on the INPUT chain that select based on the interface (-i).

It is also possible that the ISP or some other system outside the LAN is filtering connections before they reach the router; some ISPs block access to commonly-abused services.

Comment: thanks, so you are saying that this device may actually have 2 NIC interfaces? one for external WAN devices and one for internal LAN devices?

Comment: Routers traditionally have more than 1 interface, or rather how would internet facing packets get to the internal network?